# Solving parametric equation

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve these  equations

```
t + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)*Tan[θ] == x

k + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a) == y
```

where `a, b, h`, and `θ` are the coefficients.

I want the equation in the form of `y[x]`.

Comment: The variable `t` apearing inside and outside `Sin[]` in the expression for `x` dashes any hope of having a simple closed form for `y[x]`; this is similar to the situation with the cycloid.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve for `a` in the first equation and then substitute the result into the second equation:

```
sol = Solve[t + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)*Tan[θ] == x, a][[1]]
(* {a -> ((t - x) Cot[θ])/(-1 + Sin[h - t/b])} *)

FullSimplify[k + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a) /. sol]
(* k + (-t + x) Cot[θ] *)
```

Or notice that `(a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)` is equal to `-(t - x) Cot[θ]` and substitute that into the second equation.

Comment: Or in a single step `Solve[{t + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)*Tan[θ] == x, 
    k + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a) == y}, y, {a}][[1]] // Simplify`

Comment: @BobHanlon That's much more straightforward!  Very good.

Comment: Sure that this is the solution? I think the curve parameter `t` should be eliminated!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann.  Not sure.  I'm a statistician and live by "Statistics means never having to say you're certain."  I suppose the OP would need to clarify if $x$ and $y$ are parametric functions of $t$ and the rest are just arbitrary constants - although thinking about it, that does seem to be what is being asked as $t$ is not in the list of coefficients.

Comment: @JimB Thanks, perhaps the OP gives a feedback

Comment: @UlrichNeumann is right sir. I also want to eliminate the parameter "t"

Answer (score 0):

It seems only be possible to solve analytically for x[y] :

```
ergt = Solve[ k + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a) == y ,  t ] /. C[1] -> 0(*restrict solution [0,2Pi]*)
(*{{t -> h - ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a]}, {t ->h - \[Pi] + ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a]}} *)
```

Now it is possible to solve for x[y] (2 solutions):

```
{Solve[t + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)*Tan[\[Theta]] == x /. ergt[[1]], x][[1]]
,
Solve[t + (a*Sin[t/b - h] + a)*Tan[\[Theta]] == x /. ergt[[2]],x][[1]]}
(*{{x -> h - ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] - k Tan[\[Theta]] +y Tan[\[Theta]]},
{x ->h - \[Pi] + ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] - k Tan[\[Theta]] +y Tan[\[Theta]]}}*)
```

If necessary, you could further use InverseFunction for given parametervalues 
 `a,b,h,k,\[Theta]`

Answer (score 0):

Solving first for $t$

```
solt = Solve[y == a (Sin[t/b - h] + 1) + k, t] /. {C[1] -> 0}
```

and then after substitution

```
x - t - a (Sin[t/b - h] + 1) Tan[theta] /. solt // FullSimplify
```

we get at the implicit forms $(f(x,y(x))=0)$

```
-b h + x + b ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] + (k - y) Tan[theta] == 0
```

and

```
-b h + b Pi + x - b ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] + (k - y) Tan[theta] = 0
```

Follows an example with numerical values.

```
a = 1; b = 1; h = 0 Pi/4; k = 1; theta = Pi/4;
gr1 = ContourPlot[-b h + x + b ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] + (k - y) Tan[theta] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
gr2 = ContourPlot[-b h + b \[Pi] + x - b ArcSin[(a + k - y)/a] + (k - y) Tan[theta] == 0, {x, -4, 4}, {y, 0, 4}, ContourStyle -> {Thick, Blue}];
Show[gr1, gr2]
```

[image]